# Meteor: Wait until Library is ready

Tags: javascript, meteor, package, atmosphere.js

I've developed a package for Meteor where I'm including another JavaScript Library (Ziggeo) by appending their scripts to the HTML head.

Here's the source
https://github.com/Goltfisch/meteor-ziggeo/blob/master/ziggeo.js

I sometimes get an error that `ZiggeoApi` is not defined if I want to call it from within my Meteor app which uses the package.

It seems that `ZiggeoApi` is sometimes loaded a little bit slower so that it's not immediately available to the client.

How can I wait on the client until the `ZiggeoApi` function is available?

I've tested stuff like

```
Tracker.autorun ->
  if ZiggeoApi?
    console.log 'ZiggeoApi is ready'
```

or put it in `Template.foo.onRendered / Template.foo.onCreated`

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you want to make sure an appended script is loaded before doing stuff, or do you want to use an external library through a package for example? The latter is more like the "Meteor way" of doing stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I need to be sure that the script is loaded before I'm doing stuff.

Comment: By the way, unless your `ZiggeoApi` is a reactive variable, this `autorun` is going to compute once and never again. `Tracker` doesn't check if any variable changed, it checks if any **reactive** variable did.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dirty solution, check regularly that the API is present:

```
var checkForAPIInterval = Meteor.setInterval(function checkForAPI() {
  if(typeof someAPI !== 'undefined') {
    notifyAPIReady(); //Do some reactive stuff, use a plain old callback, ...
    Meteor.clearInterval(checkForAPIInterval);
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your library in a lib/ directory so it is loaded relatively soon in your app.

Here is Meteor's load order from the [Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

> 1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
> 2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
> 3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
> 4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
> 5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The Library is loaded inside a package and not in the Meteor application itself.

Comment: Does putting your calls in files starting with main. work? This thread may also help. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/LA7T55m2bzg